# Integrate Google Analytics dashboard into MVC Razor View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-4, google-analytics

I would like to have a dashboard for the administrator of my website to view as soon as he logs in to the admin section of the website, which is an MVC4 web application, using Razor view engine. I am fairly new to web development, and I can't find a simple tutorial on how to do this.

How do I go about creating a cshtml view that has a sort of "widget" or such that contains the dashboard from the google analytics website?

Answer (score 2):

Mahdi Taghizadeh has written an article that can help you retrieving the analytics data from Google and presenting it on a view:

[How to use Google Data API in ASP.NET MVC. Part 1 – Google Analytics](http://mahdi.ws/how-to-use-google-data-api-in-asp-net-mvc-part-1-google-analytics/)